# What are the URLs being accessed while installing Laravel and AsgardCMS?

Tags: php, laravel, proxy

I recently joined an organisation with a very restrictive corporate proxy policy. As we would be working primarily on Laravel and AsgardCMS, I was told to install them on the machine provided (Windows 7, limited user account).
Now, individual URLs need to be approved and whitelisted by the management here. So far, I identified two URLs I would be needing to install the above.

1. https://packagist.org/
2. https://api.github.com/

My manager asked me for a comprehensive list of URLs for him to whitelist so that he doesn't have to contact IT time and again.
This has put me in a kind of fix as I am unable to predict what URLs access the installation and subsequent running of Laravel and AsgardCMS would entail.
I tried to run iftop while running the installation on my personal machine to check which URLs are getting accessed but all it is giving me is some random IP addressed and URLs, not the list I was expecting.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure all all the endpoints its hitting during a composer install, but your list looks correct. Composer will hit packagist, which in turn will hit github.

Comment: Thanks. :) the suits at work have somewhat opened up. Could finally get an installation of Asgard CMS running on the server.